# When do we need to add 's' to a numeric year?

Tags: grammatical-number, nouns, time

I have found some statements using the format *years* instead of *year*. When do we use *years* like *1950s* and *2010s*, rather than *year* like *1950* and *2010*?

> Fish stocks here began to decline in the **1950s**, and within 20 years, there was no brown trout left.

Comment: I don't think I understand--is there a question here? Can you re-phrase?

Comment: @bikeboy389, I changed my question title and btw I just wonder can I replace the `1950s` with `1950` simply in my sample above? I am not clear about the usage conditions of `YEARS`. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer based on what I think you meant from the clarification of the original:

*1950* is specific, and *1950s* is more general, referring to the decade 1950-1959. You would use *1950* only when you are referring to that specific year. So if you mean something within the decade 1950-1959, you'd use *1950s.*

Am I answering the right question?

Answer (score 8):

*1950* refers to the single year 1950.

*1950s* refer to the period 195X, where X can be any digit.